# Where is the web project (IIS/VS Dev Server) server setting stored

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, settings, project

If I bring up the properties for a web project in Visual Studio 2010, and select the Web tab, I can choose bewteen "Use Visual Studio Development Server", "Use Local IIS Web server" and "Use Custom Web server".

There's also an option to "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)".

Where is the selection stored (IIS or VS Dev Server), if I do not select "Apply server setting to all users (store in project file)"?

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in a **.user** file located near the project file. (For instance if your project is MyProject.csproj then the user file will be MyProject.csproj.user). This .user file contains other user options, such as "ShowAllFiles".